# Хулиганизм (или хулиганство)?

Tags: лексика

Или все-таки хулиганство?
Все чаще слышу это слово. Когда-то давно я сам пытался оправдать его как исключительно сленговый термин (идеология некоторых фанатских движений), но сейчас об этом давно забыли, "хулиганизм" вытесняет хулиганство уже во всех возможных значениях. 
Откуда это? И насколько оправдано?

Comment: Первый раз слышу.

Comment: Результатов: примерно 9 460 (0,24 сек.) 
(c) google

Comment: @behemothus, исправьте как вам нравится. Только составьте информативную формулировку :)  
прошу прощения за "хулиганье".

Comment: Спасибо, нынешний вариант меня вполне устраивает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хулиганизм как околофутбольное насилие -  это, конечно, сленг. Сами футбольные хулиганы расценивают своё движение как субкультуру, часть фанатизма.
Но хулиганизм девяностых - это быстро развивающийся организм, который со временем становится все более и более самостоятельным и отходит от своей первопричины - футбола, что само по себе является закономерностью. Хулиганизм , теперь уже в качестве следствия, является для хулиганов той стороной жизни, где они могут расслабиться и "отдохнуть".Один из немецких футбольных хулиганов говорит психологам: '' Я работаю, потом иду куда-то со своей девушкой, надев при этом свои выходные брюки, и при этом я обычный человек. Но вот воскресенье, и начинается моя другая жизнь, где нет места слабости''. Но ведь это уже чистое хулиганство-нарушение общественного порядка, связанное с насилием.
(Происхождение термина хулиган точно не установлено,по одной из версий, нарицательным стало имя Патрика Хулигена, вышибалы и вора XIX века, по другой - от слова houlie, что на ирландском означает «необузданная, дикая алкогольная вечеринка», или от ирландской уличной банды Hooley gang, орудовавшей в Лондоне)

Кстати, В.Даль в первых изданиях зафиксировал слово как "хулиганизм"- поведение хулигана, то, что творят хулиганы. По значению-то получается, что это теперь одно и то же. Может, поэтому кто-то и не различает значения. А кто-то услышал новое слово, про сленг не знает, понёс его "в массы". Интернет всё стерпит.

Comment: Что именно? О хулиганизме 90-х вот:
http://landscrona.ru/zines/index.php?t=unpubl&n=03
О значении слова хулиган - из разных источников, все здесь на сайтах, о Дале - давно знала.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже нашел источник.

Comment: Будем считать, что ответ в информации о "первых изданяих" Даля. Я не знал такого.   
А "получается" действительно так.

Answer (score 5):

Честно говоря, впервые слышу слово "хулиганизм". Относительно статьи закона или просто явления — хулиганство. А хулиганье — это уже собирательное название для всех хулиганов, носящее явно оттенок ругательства.

Answer (score 3):

Опираясь  исключительно  на  чувство  языка,  хулиганство - это  поведение ( и  статья  в  УК,  разъясняющая  это  поведение ),  а  хулиганизм  -  это  идеология  такого  поведения.  Раз  уж  таковая  появилась.

Comment: Да я и сам рад бы так так толковать, да не сходится...

Comment: Пока  не  утрясётся,  могут  и  как  синонимы  использовать. "Измы"  же  не  только  за  идеологиями  закреплены.  Бандитизм,  например -  кровный  родственник  хулиганизму.

Answer (score 2):

Пришлось искать слово "хулиганизм" в поисковике, и особой популярностью оно похоже не пользуется. На беглый взгляд, это так и осталось "идеологией некоторых фанатских движений", причём исключительно футбольных. Термин как раз и описывает только эту идеологию. По крайней мере другого употребления у слова я не заметил.

Comment: Вот сейчас смотрю по Спорт-1 английскую Premier League. 
Комментатор опять сказал "хулиганизм" в отношении чего-то там, случившегося на трибунах 30 назад. Да, это тоже футбол, но уже далеко не не только фанатское и совсем уже не идеология.

В Интернете хватает ссылок и на совсем уже нефутбольное использование.

Comment: Тут скорее вопрос к комментатору.
 Опираясь исключительно на чувство языка, хулиганство - это шалость от избытка сил, и неумения их направить в нужное русло. Хулиганизм же - осознанный и целеноправленный акт хулиганства. Т.е. когда после победы на голландцами на Евро 2008 на улицу ночью выбегали болельщики, перекрывали движение, орали и жгли пиротехнику - это хулиганство. А вот когда эту пиротехнику протаскивают на стадион, чтобы отвлекать вратаря команды-соперника, просто хулиганством это уже не назовёшь, поэтому слово хулиганизм и появилось.

Comment: Ну, коли уже появилось(или возвратилось) это совершенно не употребляемое в прежние времена слово, куда ж мы все денемся?..